# Unable to use console in ZF2

Tags: php, console, zend-framework2, command-line-interface

I'm trying to access a function from my controller, using the console. It's a small application, so i only have one controller, 'IndexController'. The action i'm trying to reach is the 'buildSchemeAction'.

As i understand, you have to add routes in your "module.config.php" file, which i did as followed :

```
return array(
    'console' => array (
        'router' => array (
            'routes' => array (
                'build-scheme' => array (
                    'options' => array (
                        'route' => 'build-scheme',
                        'defaults' => array (
                            'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                            'action' => 'build-scheme'
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ), ..//
```

My Controller function looks like this :

```
public function buildSchemeAction()
{
  // logic here
}
```

When i enter the following in console :

```
php index.php build-scheme
```

i get :

```
Zend Framework 2.2.5 application
Usage:

Reason for failure: Invalid arguments or no arguments provided
```

I've been searching the web, but can't find anything. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just found out why it didn't work. I had my console routes at the top of my module.config file, while this was at the very bottom :

```
// Placeholder for console routes
'console' => array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            ../
        ),
    ),
),
```

Totally overlooked it, since it was there by default.